# Babel preset working in .babelrc file but not in Webpack config file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Is there a reason to store the Babel preset in `.babelrc` instead of `webpack.config.js` apart from being able to re-use the `.babelrc` file in another project?

I have an application that works properly using the following `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0","react"]
}
```

I changed the application to another Webpack structure without a `.babelrc` file. Here is the `webpack.config.js`:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'] }
      },
```

Strangely, the application stopped working with problems parsing JSX and `import` keywords inside my `server.js` file. It only works when I add back the `.babelrc` file. Can anyone please explain why it only works with the `.babelrc` file?

Comment: It sounds like your server.js file is not using Webpack but relying on babel-node / babel-register?

Comment: the server.js file IS using Webpack.config

Comment: I dont actually know what you mean, but you could be onto something as I found a line require('babel-core/register') in the server file but at the same time it links (ie imports) the webpack.config file

Comment: When you say it's 'using' Webpack, do you mean server.js is a bundle generated by Webpack or do you mean server.js requires in `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: The second one, server.js requires webpack.config.js

Comment: I imagine it's therefore using webpack-dev-middleware / webpack-dev-server to do something with it, what that does mean is that code is not being run through the babel-loader, you need to define the .babelrc so babel-core/register can read the config

Comment: Can you share how your Node server uses Webpack? It seems that your server might be the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loader to `babel-loader` in your `webpack.config.js` and before that you need to install them using

```
npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Also make sure you have installed `babel-preset-react`

command

**webpack.config.js**

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy'], 
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: nope, unfortunately that's not the answer as it's still not doing anything. I have other apps that uses babel like the above and not babel-loader and they still work.

Comment: check the update thats how I use the webpack module and it works for me. let me know if it works now

Comment: no, I added those plugins, but it's still insisting on me to put in the .babelrc file.

Comment: the error was about Syntax error relating to jsx and 'import' as key word. But found out something new - my original server.js file had require('babel-core/register') in it, and I must have .babelrc file to work, however when I changed my server.js file by removing 'require('babel-core/register')'; the app worked when I removed the .babelrc . I dont really understand why, I am guessing babel rc stands for babel register-core, so the require means I must have .babelrc file

Comment: yes require('babel-core/register') uses .babelrc with presets being defined in it. So thats the reason for the problem. Its good that it is solved now

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I posted another question on css not being loaded, if you happen to have any clue, please let me know.

Comment: *> I posted another question on css not being loaded...*
Bother to attach a link to your question?

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack config instead of passing the `query` option you can setup babel options using the `babel` keyword:

```
babel: {
  babelrc: false,
  presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
  plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
},
modules: {
  loaders: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

This seems to have fixed the problem for me. Unfortunately, I don't exactly know why this works :-(

You can see some of the babel-loader tests are using this to setup options:
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/blob/master/test/options.test.js#L70